# Mailgun message going into outlook spam debug

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, mailgun

I am sending emails from users via mailgun to another users email inbox. The reply address is a generated address e.g. `HkMv_j9QG@mydomain.com` which is then routed back into the application.

I have checked an email using http://www.mail-tester.com/ and I got 10/10. However, I am getting put into the "Junk Email" folder in outlook (Gmail seems fine).

I am using `mailgun-js` and `mailcomposer` to send the MIME emails with the following code:

```
export const sendHtmlEmail = ({ from, to, replyTo, subject, html, inReplyTo }) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const mail = mailcomposer({
            from,
            to,
            subject,
            html,
            text: htmlToText.fromString(html)
        })

        mail.build((error, message) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
                return
            }

            let data = {
                to,
                message: message.toString("ascii")
            }
            if(replyTo) {
                data['h:Reply-To'] = replyTo
            }

            if(inReplyTo) {
                data['h:In-Reply-To'] = inReplyTo
                data['h:References'] = inReplyTo
            }

            mailgun.messages().sendMime(data, (error, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error)
                    return
                }

                resolve(body)
            })

        })
    })
}
```

Is there any way I can debug why I am getting put into outlook's spam folder? Or does anyone know of any additional headers I need to add?

I have a green tick on all the DNS settings - bar the "Optional DNS Records" according to their documentation:
`The CNAME record is necessary for tracking opens, clicks, and unsubscribes.`

**Domain Verification & DNS**
[image]

**Return path sender score**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What does the section **Domain Verification & DNS** in Mailgun show you?

Do you have the MX records set?

Comment: I have updated the question with an image @tobias-lins

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with sendgrid

Some of the mail providers allow you to use a dedicated ip, its generaly in premium / business plan, it prevents other people to use this ip to send "junk mail".

If you send it directly from your ip, check your sender score with https://senderscore.org/lookup.php

Comment: I've added the sender score - 88 seems okay to me? Surely this wouldn't make it hit the junk mail folder? (see screenshot in question)

Comment: your reputation is shared with other user : https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202453900-Do-I-need-a-dedicated-IP-address-

Answer (score 0):

You seem savvy and have reviewed https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/202741290-Email-deliverability-tips, no doubt. Assuming that is the case, you will start to enter the tricky realm of "why is it spam?", not "what is wrong with Mailgun?".

Does your domain have spf/txt records? Do those records have mailgun added to them?  Are you sending to an ATT/SBCglobal address (that ISP is notorious for blocking everything from mailgun). Can you get a dedicated IP from mailgun?  These are things that enhance the reputation of your sending.

You may need to work with mailgun support on this specific issue.

---

Since you indicate that "gmail is fine" I am going to now turn to your question about Outlook. This program has its own default spam handling, as do programs like Mac Mail. For outlook you can manually add your system to the "safe senders" (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_for_mac_support_team_blog/2015/06/19/junk-mail-in-outlook-for-mac-for-office-365/) but that is not a global solution. These settings do not help all the other users in the world who have outlook so you will need to go back to steps that improve your reputation as a sender.  That sends you back to working with Mailgun to improve your reputation.